# Building a robotic clamp

Tags: robotic-arm

If I had a single stepper motor how could I use it to create a robotic clamp that could simply grab hold of something like a plank of wood and release it?

Are there any standard parts that I could use for this? I'm having trouble finding out what the names of the parts would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for "parallel jaw gripper kit."  Ignoring the pneumatic designs, you will find a typical parallel jaw gripper has a set of 1:1 gears which ensure the two jaws travel at equal speeds in opposite directions, connected to parallelogram 4-bar linkages which keep the clamping jaws parallel to each other.  You can find them with or without the actuator.